# Select all rows that has either A=B OR C=D EXCEPT where ID=foo in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select all rows that has either the same username OR email as any users EXCEPT the one with ID 7.

But now it returns the row that actually has the ID 7. I was thinking that perhaps you can do some grouping of your SQL to solve this?

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

This is my SQL that I am trying with in MySQL:

```
SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = "my_username" OR email = "my@email.com" AND user_id != 7
```

Previous I was running this in SQLite3 which worked fine for the purpose. But since MySQL does not support the EXCEPT this will not work in MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = :username OR email = :email EXCEPT SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Parentheses around your AND and OR statements usually helps.

Comment: presently the system returns anyone with "my_username" OR users with "my@email.com" whose user_Id is not 7.   Without ()'s the engine processes the statements on each side of the AND together then applies the or.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put parenthesis around OR:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user
WHERE (username = "my_username" OR email = "my@email.com")
AND user_id != 7
```

Without them, `AND` will be evaluated prior to `OR` because it has [higher priority](http://dev.mysql.com/dhttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.htmloc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) and it is equivalent to:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user
WHERE username = "my_username"
   OR (email = "my@email.com" AND user_id != 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a general mistake here. You used OR and AND both in where clause without putting (). Following example should work i guess :

```
SELECT user_id FROM user 
WHERE (username = "my_username" OR email = "my@email.com") AND user_id != 7
```

You can take a look [operator precedence in my sql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of parenthesis in the right place will solve your problem:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user
WHERE (username = "my_username" OR email = "my@email.com") AND user_id != 7
```

They change the way the condition is evaluated. The logical operator `AND` has higher precedence than the `OR` operator. And this is how they work in all programming languages because this is how it was defined by the mathematical theory long before the advent of programming languages.

The parenthesis enforce the desired order of evaluation.